# Expectation on the number of geometric variables needed for their sum to exceed a threshold

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, random

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots,$ be a series of independent random variables such that $X_i\sim Geo(p_i)$, and let $T\in\mathbb N$ be a constant positive integer.

Next, define $N\triangleq \min\{{n\in\mathbb N}\mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i\ge T\}$.

> **How can we find $\mathbb E[N]$?**

(An upper bound would also work).

---

This seems like a somewhat inverse version of the [general version of Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#General_version).

Intuitively, I'd like to say that $\mathbb E[N]\approx\min\{{n\in\mathbb N}\mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i]\ge T\} = \min\{{n\in\mathbb N}\mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1/p_i \ge T\}$, but I'm looking for a formal argument.

If this helps, we can assume that $0.01\ge p_1\ge p_2\ge p_3\ge\ldots$

---

In his answer, Ian gave a solution that handles two extreme cases - one where $\min\{{n\in\mathbb N}\mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1/p_i \ge T\} = \Theta(T)$ and one where the $p_i$'s decrease exponentially and we can just look for the $i$ such that $p_i^{-1}\approx T$ as a good approximation.

However, this approach doesn't seem to work well for what I think are the interesting cases. As we have $p=\prod_{i=1}^d(1-p_i)^{x_i-1}\le \prod_{i=1}^d(1-p_d)^{x_i-1}=(1-p_d)^{T-d}$, this fails in the following example.
If we have $p_i = \Theta(1/i)$, then Ian's approach would give an a bound of $\mathbb E[N]\le T/\log T$ (after optimizing $d$), while we can expect $N$ to be of the order of $\sqrt T$. This is a near quadratic gap that this method cannot address.

Comment: That kind of thing will typically have significant error, like factor of 2 error, except if $N$ is usually large. You can formulate this problem using a Markov chain but the time inhomogeneity makes it more difficult to solve.

Comment: @Ian - do you know how to get a 2-factor with a simple argument (I don't mind having an upper bound up to a constant factor)? Thanks!

Comment: We can also assume that $0.01\ge p_1\ge p_2\ge \ldots$ and that $T$ is large if this helps.

Comment: I might suggest the martingale $Y_m = \sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i-1/p_i)$ and then an optional stopping argument.

Comment: @Michael I don't think that helps...you want to estimate $\tau$ and not $X_\tau$, and at any rate that martingale would create a "moving target".

Comment: Anyway, if you want to do something specific to this case (instead of trying to apply some general Markov chain result), I'd probably do the following. First note that any "bad set" that you decide to excise will still have $N \leq T$, so that's simple enough. Now you want to decide on a threshold for a "good set", with $X_i$ guaranteed to be large but not so large that the good set is improbable. But we know $P(X_i>x)=p_i^x$. So given any vector $x \in \mathbb{N}^d$ whose sum is at least $T$, you have $E[N] \leq dp+(1-p)T$ where $p=\prod_{i=1}^d p_i^{x_i-1}$.

Comment: From this point of view the problem is all about making $d$ small while making $p$ big, since our bound is $(d-T)p$ (ignoring the irrelevant additive constant).

Comment: @Ian - an interesting approach, but it seems to yield very loose bounds. Specifically, since $0.01\ge p_1\ge p_2\ge p_3\ge\ldots$, we will have $p\le 0.01^T$ and the would be at least $T(1 - 0.01^T$) which is almost $T$. On the other hand, we should expect $N$ to be at most $T/100$, right?

Comment: Actually, maybe it should be $p=\prod_{i=1}^d (1-p_i)^{x_i-1}$ which would make it reasonable. Any thought on how to find such a $x$ without considering specific $\{p_i\}$ values?

Comment: If you fix $d$, then maximizing $\prod_{i=1}^d (1-p_i)^{x-1}$ (through its logarithm of course) subject to $\sum_{i=1}^d x_i=T$ and $x_i \geq 0$ seems like a fairly routine optimization problem. You of course don't need an exact solution to it, so you can just approximate; naturally, you want to take $x_i$ bigger for the smaller $p_i$, since intuitively each increment of $x_i$ "costs" $-\ln(1-p_i)$. I think the tricky problem will be to adjust $d$, but $d$ is basically just supposed to be a "slightly high but not that unusually high" value of $N$, so you should be able to estimate that.

Comment: @Ian- Maybe I'm doing the math wrong, but it still seems to be far from the actual expectation. For example, consider $p_i = 1/(100i)$. 
We should expect that $N$ will be $O(\log T)$, right?
But if we set $d=O(\log T)$, we get $p\le (1-1/O(\log T))^T\le e^{-\Omega(T/\log T)}$. This means that $p$ is tiny and we get a bound of $\Omega(T)$, right?

Comment: If $p_i$ scale like $1/i$ then $1/p_i$ scale like $i$ so that the sum of the expectations (and thus presumably of the random variables) scales like $n^2$ and so you expect typical values on the order of $\sqrt{T}$.

Comment: @Ian - you're right, but setting $d=O(\sqrt T)$ would still give $p\le (1-1/O(\sqrt T))^T\le e^{-\Omega(\sqrt T)}$ and a bound of $\Omega(T)$, so it seems that this can't give a constant factor, right?

Comment: @RB Are you sure? Let's say $p_i$ is $1/(2i)$, so that for large $T$ we expect $E[N]$ to be pretty much $\sqrt{T}$. Now an increment of $x_i$ costs $-\ln(1-1/(2i))$. Set $d=\sqrt{T}$, equidistribute the cost between the $x_i$, guaranteeing a total sum of $T$, so $x_i$ is like $\frac{T}{Z} (-\ln(1-1/(2i))^{-1}$ where $Z$ is a normalization constant. Now how does $p$ behave? It seems like it should be of order $1$.

Comment: @RB No, remember the product goes only up to $d$, so the exponent is like $\sqrt{T}$ and the overall quantity $p$ is of order $1$. Of course you actually want it to be quite close to the actual number $1$, which means that you may need to take $d$ a bit larger.

Comment: @Ian - unfortunately, $1-p=\Theta(1)$ gives $\Omega(T)$ bound, right? (as we have a $(1-p)T$ additive factor). If we make d larger by a constant factor I suspect we can't get away from $1-p=\Theta(1)$.

Comment: Basically you want to select $d$ such that both terms are of the same order in $T$. So for instance if you anticipate an overall bound on the order of $T^{1/2}$ then you need to choose $d$ on the order of $T^{1/2}$ but also large enough that $(1-p)$ can be ensured to be on the order of $T^{-1/2}$. I think this can be done with some care.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure such $p,d$ exist.

Comment: Also, we need the sum of $x_i$ to be $T$, right?  then we do have $p\le(1-p_d)^T$, right?

Comment: You have $p \leq (1-p_d)^d$ (given the monotonicity assumption from the question).

Comment: I'm not sure why. You need $x$ to sum up to $T$. then $p=\prod_{i=1}^d(1-p_i)^{x_i-1}\le \prod_{i=1}^d(1-p_d)^{x_i-1}=(1-p_d)^{T-d}$. (as $p_1\ge p_2\ge \ldots$). (I appologize as I have to leave now, but will see any further comments tomorrow, thanks!).

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. But this bound is too crude to handle a case like the one we were just talking about. Specifically, it is accurate in the case where $p_i$ decrease very rapidly, such that the contribution to the sum of $1/p_i$ is mostly from the very last term. In this case you get a more or less trivial bound of "$d$ times the probability $p$ that the $d$th term is big enough by itself, plus $(1-p)T$".

Answer (score 2):

You mention you're already interested in the case of constant $p_i=p$. In that case I believe an exact answer is easy. For the moment I assume your geometric random variables take strictly positive integer values, i.e. $P(X_i=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$ for $k=1,2,\dots$.

Write $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then the sums $S_n$ are distinct. Let us consider the places where the random walk $S_n$ stops; i.e. for each positive integer $m$, consider the event that there is $n$ such that $S_n=m$.

In fact, this event has probability $p$ for each $m$, and the events are independent for different $m$.

(To see this, observe that by basic properties of geometric random variables, we can think of the random walk $S_n$ as follows. To increment the walk, repeatedly step up by $1$, after each step stopping with probability $p$. The probability that any given integer $m$ is a stopping point is $p$, and all these stopping events are independent.)

So in fact the size of the set of stopping points $\{m\in\{1,2,\dots,T-1\}: S_n=m \text{ for some }n\}$ has Binomial$(T-1, p)$ distribution, and so mean $p(T-1)$.

Your $N$ is simply $1$ more than the number of these stopping points. Hence $E[N]=p(T-1)+1$.

If you want instead geometrics which can take the value $0$, i.e. $P(X_i=k)=(1-p)^k p$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$, then a simple adjustment gives $E[N]=(1-p)^{-1}p(T-1)+(1-p)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I'm also interested in constant $p$ values is that it already gives asymptotically optimal to scenarios with distinct $p_i$'s. For example, consider the case where $p_i = 1/i$. Then we expect $N$ to be $O(\sqrt T )$. Now we can bound it by saying that there are $O(\sqrt T)$ variables that have probability higher than $1/\sqrt T$. Thus these add $O(\sqrt T)$ to $N$ and all others, by your answer for fixed $p$ also add at most $O(Tp)=O(\sqrt T)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to split the space into a single good set and a single bad set. The good set is meant to be highly probable and yet also have good values of $N$; the bad set is meant to be highly improbable but perhaps contain bad values of $N$, hopefully still not so bad that we can't control them. One way to do this is to consider the "good" set

$$B=B(x)=\{ X_1 \geq x_1,X_2 \geq x_2,\dots,X_d \geq x_d \}$$

where $x$ is a vector of nonnegative integers satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^d x_i=T.$

We have

$$P(B)=\prod_{i=1}^d q_i^{x_1-1}$$

where $q_i=1-p_i$. On $B(x)$, $N \leq d(x)$. On $B(x)^c$, $N \leq T$ (and this is the best we can do uniformly over all of $B(x)^c$). Thus

$$E[N] \leq d(x) P(B(x)) + (1-P(B(x)) T$$

for any $x$. So the question is to find a good $x$. Suppose $f(T)$ is the "mean field" solution, i.e.

$$f(T)=\min \left \{ n : \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{-1} \geq T \right \}.$$

Presumably $N$ is typically around $f(T)$. So we should choose $x$ with $d(x)$ a bit bigger than $f(T)$, so that $1-P(B(x))$ is small, but not so much bigger that the first term becomes large. If we don't care about constant factors, then there are three cases:

- $f(T)=\Theta(T)$. In this case $E[N]$ is also $\Theta(T)$, so up to constant factors we're done.
- $\frac{p_n^{-1}}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{-1}} \to L>0$ as $n \to \infty$. (For example this happens if $p_i$ decay exponentially.) In this case the sum more or less does not matter, the whole thing is dominated by the very last term, so we can think of the first term as just $d p_d^{T-1}$ and the second term as $(1-p_d)T$. Set these equal and solve for $d$, more or less.
- The intermediate case. In this case you basically need to set $d$ to be a bit bigger than $f(T)$ to take into account fluctuations, and then carefully select $x$ to "evenly distribute the cost". In other words you will want to choose $x$ such that $x_i$ is proportional to $-\ln(q_i)^{-1}$. The extent to which $d$ has to exceed $f(T)$ is so that both terms in the inequality for $E[N]$ are of the same order; the exact behavior of this will vary a fair bit depending on the specifics of the problem. But once you have chosen $d$ it should not be too bad to pick $x_i$ to be a "rounding" of $\frac{T}{Z_d} (-\ln(q_i))^{-1}$ where $Z_d$ is a normalization constant, and thereby obtain a lower bound for $P(B(x))$ and thus an upper bound for $E[N]$ from above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm mainly interested in the ``intermediate case'', for which this approach doesn't seem to yield good upper bounds. For example, if $p_i=1/i$, this gives a bound that is almost quadratic compared to what we can expect.